# Style change Binding Path value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code in 2-3 places and the common is the style except binding path "BidMovement" need to be changed in other places ("AskMovement", "StaleMovement").
Is this possible in WPF, to define style and change some of the elements (binding path) when its actually used?

```
<Border Name="BidBorder" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5" Margin="5" CornerRadius="10">
   <Border.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BidMovement}" Value="{x:Static crosses:PriceMovement.Up}">
               <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BidMovement}" Value="{x:Static crosses:PriceMovement.Down}">
               <Setter  Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BidMovement}" Value="{x:Static crosses:PriceMovement.Stale}">
               <Setter  Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Comment: I would create a UserControl with a MovementType DP that changes the background in its callback function. Then you would only have to use it like this: <YouUserControl MovementType="{Binding ...}"/> instead of typing the full style everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ValueConverter` that converts the `Movements` into `Brushes`. It would look like this:

```
public class MovementToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var movement = value as Movement;
        if (movement == PriceMovement.Up)
            return Brushes.Green;
        //return values for the other cases accordingly

        return Brushes.Transparent; //default
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it add the namespace of your application to the namespaces and add the converter as a static resource to the windows resources:

```
<Window //other attributes omitted for brevity
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:YourApplication">
<Window.Resources>
    <l:MovementToBrushConverter x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then define the binding on your border and add the value converter, like this:

```
<Border Background="{Binding BidMovement, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"></Border>
```